# Using two foreach functions together?

Tags: php, foreach

I have an online application built using PHP, for saving multiple risk assessments. The user can type a title, date and signature in the web form, select the risk assessments they want and press save. This will save the documents on the server in the folder specified, with the same title, date etc., added to each one.

However, I have been asked to implement text boxes under each selected risk assessment to add individual comments to each one. My current code loops through each selected risk assessment, adding the same information to each one. How do I now add unique comments to each one. I assume I need to use another foreach function for this, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Current Code:

```
//'files' are the risk assessments selected using checkboxes.
foreach($_POST['files'] as $selected){

    $template1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("templates/$selected.docx");

    $template1->setValue('fldProject_Title', str_replace('&', '&amp;', $_POST['title']));

    $template1->setValue('JobNo', $_POST['JobNo']);

    $template1->setValue('fldDatePrep', $_POST['date']);

    $template1->setValue('sub', $_POST['sub']);

    $filepath1 = "P_DRIVE/$JobNo/$sub/Health and Safety/Risk Assessments/$selected.docx";

    $template1->saveAs($filepath1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out for anyone that's interested.

By matching the files array index with the notes array index.

```
$_POST['files'] = array_values(array_filter($_POST['files']));
foreach($_POST['files'] as $key1 => $selected)
{
    $template1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("templates/$selected.docx");

    $template1->setValue('fldProject_Title', str_replace('&', '&amp;', $_POST['title']));

    $template1->setValue('JobNo', $_POST['JobNo']);

    $template1->setValue('fldDatePrep', $_POST['date']);

    $template1->setValue('sub', $_POST['sub']);

    $notesArray = array_values(array_filter($_POST['notes']));
    foreach($notesArray as $key2 => $notes)
    {
        if($key1 == $key2)
        {
            $template1->setValue('notes', $notes);
        }
    }

    $filepath1 = "P_DRIVE/$JobNo/$sub/Health and Safety/Risk Assessments/$selected.docx";

    $template1->saveAs($filepath1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just nest a foreach inside that one.

```
foreach($_POST['files'] as $selected){

    $template1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("templates/$selected.docx");

    $template1->setValue('fldProject_Title', str_replace('&', '&amp;', $_POST['title']));

    $template1->setValue('JobNo', $_POST['JobNo']);

    $template1->setValue('fldDatePrep', $_POST['date']);

    $template1->setValue('sub', $_POST['sub']);

    $filepath1 = "P_DRIVE/$JobNo/$sub/Health and Safety/Risk Assessments/$selected.docx";

    foreach ($_POST['comments'] as $comment) {
       // perform actions
    }

    $template1->saveAs($filepath1);
}
```

Comment: This just posts the last comment in all the risk assessments. Because it loops through every comment in each POST['files'] if you see what I mean.

Comment: Not familiar with your post var structure, I just gave an example but if you send us an example from `print_r($_POST)` replacing values with dummy data sure we can take a look

Comment: Thank you, but I've now managed to solve this. I've posted my answer above.